# GetWindowRect always returning same values

Tags: c#, winapi

I know that similar questions have been posted already, but the proposed solutions did not work for me.

I am trying to get a window position in the screen. The only value I really care is the **Top-Left point** of this window, **without the Top-Title bar**.

This is the function I am using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
```

Where RECT is defined as follow:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }
```

So I keep getting always the same values for the window being in different positions of the screen:

```
Bottom = screen_height
Right = screen_width
Top = -4 // <--
Left = -4 // <--
```

**OS:** Windows 7.

**App:** This is a Surface App (using Surface SDK 2.0)

**UPDATE:**

After a series of comments, it was suggested to use Spy++ to double check the Window Handle. I then found out that the Handle returned by Spy++ was different from the one I was using.
When manually changing the Handle (in Debug mode), I started to get some more reasonable results.

This is how I am getting the Window Handle:

```
public partial class SurfaceWindow1 : SurfaceWindow
{

    public SurfaceWindow1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        ....
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Just to be more informative, here is a picture of what I'd like to get (ignore the keyboard at the bottom):

[image]

Comment: Those coordinates look like the window is maximized - is it? And what do you mean "without the top-title bar"? Are you talking about the position of the client area?

Comment: No, the window is not maximized. By top-title bar I mean the one containing the name of the window, and the little icons to minimize/maximize/close the window. Sorry for the wrong terminology

Comment: Well, what does `GetWindowRect` return? And how can we reproduce this? IIRC, maximised coords are -8, -8, ScreenRight+8, ScreenBottom+8

Comment: @DavidHeffernan GetWindowRect returns true. TBH, I am not sure how this could be reproduced. My application is Surface (SDK 2.0) Application. Does that matter?

Comment: Er, yes, it really matters that this is WinRT. You need to make that really clear in the Q.

Comment: I am running Windows 7, no WinRT or Win8.

Comment: That blog post link is *very* unconvincing.  Use Spy++ instead.

Comment: Despite your comment to the contrary it sounds like you might be using the wrong window handle. Do any of the other ones return reasonable data for GetWindowRect?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Other windows return the same unreasonable result.

Comment: @HansPassant I used Spy++ and found out the Handle was different. When I manually edited the Handle (in debug mode) I started getting different results. I imagine I am getting the window handle not the right way. I am using this: new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle from my class that extends: SurfaceWindow

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will give you the client rectangle of the window. The `left` and `top` values will be `(0, 0)`, but the `right` and `bottom` give you the width and the height.

You can then call [ClientToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the window handle and a point of `(0,0)`. That will give you the screen coordinates of the client area's top-left corner. Just add the width and height (from the previous call to `GetClientRect`), and you'll have it.

Comment: I solved using FindWindow(). This gave me the correct window handle. I still appreciate the effort Jim. Thanks